# Summation of each column by selected few specific rows - in R

Tags: r

I have started learning R recently. For one of my codes, I have been trying to debug this issue for quite a while.

I have the data which looks like this:

```
dd
    [,1]       [,2]   [,3] 
[1,] "Category" "A"    "B"  
[2,] "ONE"      "23"   "45" 
[3,] "TWO"      "234"  "23" 
[4,] "THREE"    "565"  "324"
[5,] "FOUR"     "676"  "343"
[6,] "FIVE"     "1231" "544"
```

I want to add rows: ONE, THREE and FIVE (in Category) for each of the columns. Therefore, the output will look like:

```
sum  1819   913
```

I have tried to use rowSums and sum. I get error every time I use this. One of the most common error is shown below.

```
sum = rowSums(subset(dd, CATEGORY == 'ONE', 'THREE', 'FIVE'))
Error in rowSums(subset(spread_DNT_TXN, CATEGORY == "Invoiced")) : 
  'x' must be numeric
```

I am looking for how I can perform this function. I am unable to find it anywhere.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It won't work, because the columns are all character.  Try `m1 <- matrix(as.numeric(dd[-1, 2:3]), ncol = 2); i1 <- dd[-1, 1] %in% c("ONE", "THREE", "FIVE"); rowSums(m1[i1, ])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R you can do:

```
# Load your data first
dd <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = '
"Category" "A"    "B"  
"ONE"      "23"   "45" 
"TWO"      "234"  "23" 
"THREE"    "565"  "324"
"FOUR"     "676"  "343"
"FIVE"     "1231" "544"')

# Summarize by selected catagories
colSums(subset(dd, Category %in% c("ONE", "THREE", "FIVE"), select = -Category))
#   A    B 
#1819  913
```

Or alternatively using `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(cbind(A, B) ~ 1, 
          data = subset(dd, Category %in% c("ONE", "THREE", "FIVE")),
          FUN = sum)
#     A   B
#1 1819 913
```

and perhaps more R idiomatic:

```
dd$ofInterest <- dd$Category %in% c("ONE", "THREE", "FIVE")
aggregate(cbind(A, B) ~ ofInterest, data = dd, FUN = sum)
#  ofInterest    A   B
#1      FALSE  910 366
#2       TRUE 1819 913
```

Answer (score 0):

To start, you can use the `%in%` operator and `colSums`:

```
colSums( dd[dd$Category %in% c("ONE", "THREE", "FIVE"), c("A", "B") )
```

However, I recommend using `data.table` rather than `data.frame` or `dplyr`. I find slicing and grouping to be very clear with this package.

First, install and load `data.table`:

```
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)
```

Then turn your old `data.frame` to a `data.table`:

```
dd <- as.data.table(dd)
```

Now sum:

```
dd[Category %in% c("ONE", "THREE", "FIVE"), list(Sum_of_A = sum(A), Sum_of_B = sum(B))]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in `base R`.  Note that the OP's dataset is a `matrix` and matrix can hold only a single class.  If there is one character element, the whole matrix will be converted to `character` class.  Here, for some reason, the headers are the first row, along with the fact that first column is `character`.  One option would be to subset the numeric columns, convert the type, and then select the rows of interest for `rowSums`

```
m1 <- matrix(as.numeric(dd[-1, 2:3]), ncol = 2)
i1 <- dd[-1, 1] %in% c("ONE", "THREE", "FIVE")
rowSums(m1[i1, ])
#[1]   68  889 1775
```

Or if it needs to be column wise sum

```
colSums(m1[i1, ])
#[1] 1819  913
```

#### data

```
dd <- cbind(c("Category", "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE"),
    c("A", 23, 234, 565, 676, 1231), c("B", 45, 23, 324, 343, 544))
```